# test for directory scanning/reading vulnerabilities on website

Tags: security, testing, web

Lets just say I want to test the security of a server (http://www.testserver.com) for directory scanning/reading vulnerabilities.

I would normally try to search for a file say /etc/passwd (or something more interesting:)) by doing something like http://www.testserver.com/../../../../etc/passwd and see if it throws up anything.

Now this can get quite tedious if I dont know exactly how many dots and slashes I would have to go through to find this problem.

Is there any intelligent/automatic way to do this?

P.S. I dont know what the word is for this sort of test so if I've duplicated this question kindly indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when apache or something is configured correctly, it will not let you access anything above the root directory, defined by `DocumentRoot` in your apache config.

If you have the correct `DocumentRoot` set in your apache config, then there is no problem. Usually the default configuration is safe, but of course, you may have accidentally allowed access to other folders.